# ethereum mining rig power consumption

Tags: mining, ether, power-consumption

I am planning to build a mining rig with 6x Amd PowerColor Rx 480 8GB. They require each 500 watt minimum. What PSU will be handle all of them? Maybe its better to use 2x PSU (3 card with 1 psu and the other 3 with second psu)? I am very confused because each of GPU require 500 watt minimum and i can't decide the proper PSU to handle them.

Another question which i am not sure is how to calculate the total power consumption by whole system. I made some calculation online and my system needs 945 watt. This is the power consumed in 1 hour or 24 hour? Because i need to make a prediction on how money will i use for electricity.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The 500W minimum you are referring to is for the entire system, including a single card, the motherboard, cpu, fans etc.

The cards themselves probably only max out around 200W each, likely less while mining.

So, you have the 500W minimum including one of the cards, then add the remaining 5 cards @ 200W each for 1000W, and you're looking at 1500W total.

I would recommend going for 2x 1000W PSUs. This gives you some headroom on both so they are not running at full capacity all the time.

The 945W you refer to is the power consumed at any given instant.